# Linux: change I/O scheduler for partition not entire device?

Tags: linux, io, scheduler, partition

I want to change the I/O scheduler on a system using these commands:

```
echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo 'echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler' >> /etc/rc.local
```

Is it possible to change the scheduler on an individual partition, e.g. `sda3`?

Comment: Can you tell us where this strange requirement comes from?

Comment: It's not really a requirement.  The only examples I see discussed on the web involve changing all of sda.  I assume that that means the scheduler is set for all partitions for that device (sorry if I'm conceptually confused about devices, partitions and so forth here...), but didn't see any explicit claim that it actually had to be that way.

Comment: @scal What if you have two different file system types on the same disk in separate partitions and those file systems perform better with different I/O schedulers?